# How to create Hub like Overview,Rooms in TFS 2015 web

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

How can I create a hub like the Overview or Rooms tabs in Team Foundation Server 2015?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.  Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create additional hubs in TFS, you will want to create an [extension](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview).

To create a hub under a specific hub group, you can [create a contribution by following this tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/contributions-overview).

You can use the [seed project](https://github.com/cschleiden/vsts-extension-ts-seed-simple) to get started or [the existing extension samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples) for some examples.

Note that [you will need TFS 2015 Update 3 or higher](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions).

For clarity, hubs and hub groups can only be created inside of projects. See this list of extension points for all of the places you can [extend things](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/targets/overview).

Comment: Thank you hross. I ;have on doubt.
Is that hub will appear before i enter inside any project i.e before i browse any project?

Product name - Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015
Hub 1  - Overview 
Hub2   -   Rooms   
Hub3 - Test

Comment: You are correct that you cannot create a hub at this level (outside of a project). The highest you can go is a [hub group](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-hub-group). Here is a list of all the currently supported [extension points](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/targets/overview)